Cut a 2D square by a line to make two new paths. the goal is to cut the square twice and have four paths
I am trying to use the code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730726/319072 to cut a square into four pieces (i.e. cut it by two lines and obtain the four paths). The goal is to fill each one individually in manual order.
I have used this code successfully before, but for some reason it is not working in an MWE I've been trying to make. For example, if works for me in even 3D planes.
Since this is just one question, I will accept it if someone can explain by the first line isn't cutting the square. I would then elaborate on is in a second question. Of course, if you know how, you are more than welcome to post that here too.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[spath/save=mySquare,red] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[spath/save=lineOne,green] (-5,0) -- (0,5);
\draw[spath/save=lineTwo,blue] (-5,5) -- (5,-5);

\scoped[
    spath/split at intersections={mySquare}{lineOne},
    spath/remove components={mySquare}{0},
]
\fill[opacity=0.1]
(spath cs:{mySquare} 1)
[spath/use={mySquare}]
[spath/use={lineOne}]
--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



So I think there may be several issues here and I only claim to have possibly identified at most a couple of them.

The path you are trying to fill includes the entire square, in addition to the part you want to fill.
However, the path isn't closed, so there is nothing to fill at all.
Simply listing components and then listing another path doesn't make them into a single continuous path. You just have a discontinuous path.
lineOne needs to extend at each end to ensure it cuts mySquare. Doing this makes a dramatic difference, even though it initially still gave me undesired results.

By way of troubleshooting advice:

It is easier to see what is or may be happening if you draw as well as fill. Preferably use a thick, bright line which can't be confused with other lines in your diagram. That way, if the path isn't closed (so doesn't fill), you can still see where it goes (at least in general terms).
Remove any scoping from the affected code unless that is what you are troubleshooting until you are confident the rest works.

This is not presented as a solution but, rather, as a step towards one which may help you to figure out what is happening and what you might need to do to make it work. It is clear from the result that the code is incorrect. The cyan line should not descend to (-5,-5). I offer it merely as progress of a kind1.
The result is not meant to be pretty, but potentially informative:

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[spath/save=mySquare,red] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
  \draw[spath/save=lineOne,green] (-5.1,0) -- (0,5.1);
  \draw[spath/save=lineTwo,blue] (-5,5) -- (5,-5);

  \scoped[
    spath/.cd,
    split at intersections={mySquare}{lineOne},
    remove components={mySquare}{0},
    join components with={mySquare}{lineOne}{1},
    close={mySquare},
  ]
  \fill[opacity=1,
    draw=cyan,ultra thick,
    spath/.cd,
    remove components={mySquare}{0},
    use={mySquare},
  ]
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

1I will delete this when somebody posts a proper answer or update it if I find time to fiddle with it first (or somebody leaves me a hint, though people rarely do that these days).

Sorry for accepting there, I realize your intention is to delete this. It is informative though.

I was able to get this to work for a second cut. Thank you very much for your help. Would it be okay to accept this?

@Jasper I guess, if you really want to :-). but I don't expect that ;).

I was able to get this to work in my more advanced case already, thank you.
